Nested JSON/array to CSV
I'm making API calls in a for loop and exporting some of the fields from each call to a CSV file.
$csvres = foreach ($a in $k) {
    $uri = "https://......./"+$k
    $ApiRes = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method get -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
    $t = $ApiRes.tags
    foreach ($i in $t) {
        if (($i.key -eq "Not enabled") -and (!$ApiRes.state)) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Id'    = $ApiRes.Id
                'State' = $ApiRes.state
                'TK'    = $ApiRes.tags.key
                'TV'    = $ApiRes.tags.value
            }
        }
    }
}
$csvres | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation

This does work and store all the 4 fields that I want. But the catch the JSON result from $Apires.tags sometimes has one key and sometimes multiple. So in the CSV when it's single it gets stores properly but when multiple I just get System.Object[].
Consider this as the multiple pair result:
$ApiRes
Id  :  510326
type:  Type3
state: false
tags:  @{active=true;key=Not enabled;value=G78 19/05/2000},@{active=true;key=locked Id}
Position: Not Designated

and this as the single one:
$ApiRes
Id  :  998652
type:  Type1
state: false
tags:  @{active=true;key=Not enabled;value=N52}
Position: Not Designated

The CSV with these two looks like:
Id     State    TK                 TV
510326 false    System.Object[]    G78 19/05/2000
998652 false    Not enabled        N52

This is what I have so far. But even if this system.object gets fixed I am still unable to figure how to export just the key= Not enabled and its corresponding value. I do not want the other keys if they are present. Just like it can have multiple keys there can also be values associated with it. I have tried $ApiRes.key[0] $ApiRes.value[0] but realized that Not enabled wouldn't always be the first one.
I can filter out only the $k results which has this key using the if condition but am unable to just export this key alone with its corresponding value.
Desired csv result- (In the first row TK, where the JSON result has 2 keys, I do not want the second key LockedId and just need Not enabled)
Id     State    TK                 TV
510326 false    Not enabled        G78 19/05/2000
998652 false    Not enabled        N52


Please add a sample Json of the API response and the desired CSV output

@MathiasR.Jessen I had to type this out as I couldn't copy. I corrected  the typos this should be now correct.

@SantiagoSquarzon I have added the desired result. The sample Json is mentioned - $ApiRes. As the API call is made multiple times I have added two sample Json

The issue with your code is caused by a typo on $ApiRes.tags.key and $ApiRes.tags.value when they should be $i.Key and $i.Value

@SantiagoSquarzon My bad, as I typed this out I wrote it incorrectly. I just corrected that.

my comment still applies. the enumerated item is $i in your code.

You're running two loops and inside each are referencing the wrong variable. In the first loop, you declare $a but use $k (which $a should be enumerating $k) and then the second loop you iterate the tags with $i but then don't reference it in your pscustomobject where you should, you instead use $ApiRes. Is your first loop even needed? Also, please consider how terrible those variable names are.

You need a customobject for each row in the CSV. So you need [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $i.Key, Value = $i.Value }
